# Is it possible to take pods directly offline in kubernetes loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I have an app running on three pods behind a loadbalancer, all set up with Kubernetes. My problem is that when I take pods down or update them, this results in a couple of 503s before the loadbalancer notices the pod is unavailable and stops sending traffic to it. Is there any way to inform the loadbalancer directly that it should stop sending traffic to a pod? So we can avoid the 503s on pod update

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep in mind if the pods are down the loadbalancer will still be redirecting the traffic to the designated service ports, and as no pod is servicing those ports.

Hence you should use rolling update mechanism in kubernetes which gives zero down time to the deployment. [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 3 pods running behind a Load balancer, I believe you must be using Deployment/Statefulset to manage them.

If by updating the pods you mean updating docker image version running in the pod then you can make use of *[Update strategies in Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment)* to do rolling update. This will update your pods with zero downtime.

Additionally you can also make use of [startup, readiness and liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes) to only direct traffic to the pod when the pod is ready/live to serve traffic.

Comment: Yup, I'm using a deployment, and I'm using the set image command to roll out updates. This provides almost zero downtime but not actual zero downtime - I'm still seeing a couple requests come through returning 503. What I want is to be able to mark the pod as offline before it's actually going down.

Comment: In this case you can make use of the Pod Eviction Lifecycle. When the kubelet is asked to delete a pod, it executes the `pre-stop` hook and waits for the grace period seconds(default 30s) before actually sending the TERM signal or deleting the pod. In your case you need to write a pre-stop hook which will stop accepting any new incoming connections post serving the current one. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement probes for pods. Read [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

Answer (score 0):

There are `readinessProbe` and `LivenessProbes` which you can make use of. In your case I think you can make use of readinessProbe, only when your readinessProbe will pass, kubernetes will start sending traffic to your Pod.

For example

```
apiVersion: v1
Kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my-nginx-pod
spec:
 containers: 
 - name: my-web-server
   image: nginx
   readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
     path: /login
     port: 3000
```

in this above example, the nginx Pod will only receive traffic in case it passed the readinessProbe.

You can find more about probes here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Comment: I have - that hasn't fixed the issue though. I will still have some requests being sent to the pod before the loadbalancer cuts it out. The problem is that the pod goes down/gets marked unhealthy, and the loadbalancer reacts on that - so it will still send a couple of requests before removing the pod from the pool.